# Why can't we "heal" Tinnitus by destroying the corresponding neurons?

Tags: hearing, cure, tinnitus

So, my basic understanding is this:

A neuron can either send a signal, or not. Sending a signal costs energy & work (and the neuron might only survive so and so many send-cycles).

So let's say the output of a neuron tells you whether a state is assumed, or not. 
To keep the neuron alive and energy consumption low, if the state being assumed is the rarer occasion, then the neuron sends a signal if the state is being assumed, and vice versa.
I'd now guess that hearing a sound (or more low level, a sound wave being of a certain frequency being in the air), is more unlikely than the converse.

So for a person with a Tinnitus that produces a constant sound, somewhere in the brain/the receptory neurons for hearing, we should have one/a few neurons that fire permanently.

We should know rather broadly where the information processing for sounds happens, and neurons that always send should be anomalies (as a neuron that always sends doesn't transmit any information at all).

So why can't we just scan for neurons in those regions permanently firing, and then destroy them?

Comment: How would individual neurons be located and measured? How would they be destroyed without destroying surrounding neurons? How would the patient not end up with total deafness in the frequencies sensed by the destroyed neurons?

Comment: @CareyGregory As far as I know, it is not uncommon that a Tinnitus is created especially because of partial deafness in the corresponding frequencies. Then there's the fraction of people with that illness that would be willing to accept that tradeback. I'd  guess that it's more than one neuron going haywire, as otherwise Tinnitus would more regularly "spontaneously heal" (by the neuron dying). So, if it is a small cluster of neurons gone haywire, is it that we can't pinpoint its location that's stopping us from testing whether destroying it works?

Comment: I don't know how finely doctors can identify neurons and destroy them selectively without destroying entire regions. Do you? Seems to me that ought to be part of your question as prior research.

Comment: @CareyGregory The destroy part shouldn't be the problem. The linear accelerators I looked at were about to 1cm precise, IMRT is more precise, and proton accelerators, even though experimental, should be even more precise. So the destroying part probably isn't the problem. fMRI on the other hand allows us to image brain activity to pixels of size 0.5mm (and a little smaller). So, altogether, I'd say in regular circumstances, precision of fMRI is limited to clusters of ~10k neurons. Since we're looking for permanently active neurons, that threshold should actually a bit lower.

Comment: I'm thinking that destroying 10k neurons almost anywhere in the brain can quite possibly have profound, unintended effects, so that puts us back to how finely surgeons can identify targets in a living human brain. At the individual neuron level? I seriously doubt that. At the 10k group level? Maybe, but I kind of doubt that too. Adding credible links to get me past these doubts would make your question a lot better. Right now it's one of those "Did really smart people spend decades missing the obvious answer I just thought of?" kind of questions.

Comment: @CareyGregory That's basically what it is, yes. Since this is an obvious idea, I thought that somebody who studied in this direction would have no trouble pointing out the fault in my logic. Please don't think I'm thinking lowly of the medical sciences, or that I'm sitting here thinking everybody but me is stupid. I was just curious why this method isn't working, and since asking two doctors in this field and my layman's research didn't lead me to an answer, I thought asking this here would be the best next step.

Comment: Well, the first reason I can think of is it would convert tinnitus into total deafness for whatever it is those 10K neurons respond to. That sounds more like harm than treatement.